# Allow saving of a number that begins with a decimal point

Tags: javascript, validation

I've got a jsp form, and a few of the fields take a dollar amount:

```
<tr id="amount" style="visibility: visible;"><td>
 <numbered>1)&nbsp </numbered>Total Compensation: US$ 
 <html:text maxlength="11" size="11" property="user.compensation" styleClass="required greaterThan0 compensation currency"/>
 <span class="mandatory">!</span>
 <br/><span class="errors"></span><br/>
</td></tr>
```

It uses jquery.validate.js for the validation, and it's been requested that we allow numbers such as ".123" (vs 0.123) to be entered and saved.

The function in js points to:

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number
number: function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
},
```

but how can I change this to allow saving of a number that begins with a decimal point?

Comment: Try changing `\d{1,3}` to `\d{0,3}`

Comment: @Halcyon, thanks for the help; still can't save though.

Answer (score 0):

this section of your regex:

```
(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)
```

Matches the digits *before* the decimal point. It matches 1 or more digits (`\d+`) *or* 1 to 3 digits followed by a comma and 3 more digits one or more times (the `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+` part)

So, just make it optional:

```
^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$
                             ^
                             |
                     Matches 0 or 1 times
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/pQ3lY2/2), and note that regex101 is a really useful tool for decoding regexes and you should use it.